# Haptic engine iPhone stronger impact

Tags: ios, swift, haptic-feedback

I have this function which creates haptic impact:

```
func generateVibration() {

    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
    generator.impactOccurred()
}
```

I would like to make the impact stronger. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func generateVibration() {

    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
    generator.impactOccurred()
    generator.impactOccurred()
}
```

The more times you call generator.impactOccured(), the stronger the impact will be.